# React Native - Download image from Facebook profile?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using React Native FBSDK to integrate my app's user profiles with their Facebook. I'm looking for a way to allow the user to download images from their Facebook to my app. Similar to how this functions in Tinder.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to do a graph request on Facebook to get more informations about a specific user.

That look something like that :

```
//first you need to sign in your user and then ...
let result = await this.FBGraphRequest('id, email, picture.type(large), last_name, first_name');

 FBGraphRequest = async (fields) => {
    const accessData = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    this.saveToken(accessData["accessToken"], "facebook");
    // Create a graph request asking for user information
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
                accessToken: accessData.accessToken,
                parameters: {
                    fields: {
                        string: fields
                    }
                }
            },
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });

        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
    });
};
```

To have much informations I redirect you to this great [medium post](https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/coding-with-facebook-login-in-react-native-like-a-pro-1x06-9064fc2f5bfc).